# Why I cannot get values from excel into a list using my codes?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I would like to gather the relevant Excel cells into a list for a sequence comparison. However, I failed to get those cell values with conditions into the list by using below codes (nothing is printed in console as expected).

I tried using `startsWith` and other condition syntax but I am not sure if this is the issue or I did sth wrong in prior.

```
    HSSFSheet dispcolsheet = workbook2.getSheet(0);
    Iterator<Row> colRowItr = dispcolsheet.rowIterator();
    List<String> colstatuslist = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (colRowItr.hasNext()){
        Row row = colRowItr.next();
        Cell colname = row.getCell(0);
        if ("ABC_".contains(colname.getStringCellValue())) {
            colstatuslist.add(row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue());
            System.out.println(colstatuslist);
        }
    }
```

My xls file looks like:

```
name   |status
ABC_1  | TRUE
ABC_2  | FALSE
ABC_3  | TRUE
.
.
.
```

I expect to store the `TRUE FALSE TRUE` from column `B` in sequence so that I could `get()` them to use for comparison, like `get(0)` would be the status of `ABC_1` as `TRUE`, `get(1)` would be the status of `ABC_2` as `FALSE` and so on.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing the *if* check the wrong direction/way.

With

```
"ABC_".contains(colname.getStringCellValue())
```

You are checking if the string `ABC_` *contains* (or *has*) the cell value.

Does `ABC_` contain `ABC_1` - No

You should reverse it as

```
colname.getStringCellValue().contains("ABC_") 

or 
colname.getStringCellValue().startsWith("ABC_")
```

Does `ABC_1` contain/startsWith `ABC_` - Yes

Answer (score 3):

I find it best to use [StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#contains-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) for String comparisons. You can do,

```
StringUtils.contains(colname.getStringCellValue(), "ABC_") 
StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(colname.getStringCellValue(), "ABC_")
```

Very simple.